# Saving TRANSFORM table in MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to save following query result into permanent table:

```sql
TRANSFORM Min(SOIL_SPECIES_CD) AS Expr1 
    SELECT ARODES_INT_NUM
    FROM F_AROD_SOIL_SPEC
    GROUP BY ARODES_INT_NUM
    PIVOT SOIL_RANK_ORDER;
```

I've tried things like:

```sql
SELECT * INTO soil FROM (TRANSFORM Min(SOIL_SPECIES_CD) AS Expr1 
    SELECT ARODES_INT_NUM
    FROM F_AROD_SOIL_SPEC
    GROUP BY ARODES_INT_NUM
    PIVOT SOIL_RANK_ORDER);
```

but I'm getting Syntax error in FROM clause.
What is the proper way to save such table in MS Access SQL?

Answer (score 1):

[Apparently](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/making-a-table-from-crosstab-query.694135/), you [can't](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/generating-a-new-table-via-crosstab-query.297099/).

You need to save your crosstab (TRANSFORM) query as query object, then use this as source.

```
SELECT * INTO soil FROM myTransformQuery
```